# Facebook login/logout button does not work correctly in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login, facebook-authentication

I have the following scenario. I have a `LoginActivity` and the `MainActivity`. In the `LoginActivity` I have added the `Facebook LoginButton`. Once I'm successfully authenticated, I'm automatically redirected to the `MainActivity`.

I have also added a auth listener in both activities to check if the user is authenticated or not. The problem is, when I sign-out from the `MainActivity` and I'm redirected to the `LoginActivity` the `Facebook LoginButton` shows me `Log out` instead of `Continue with...`. How can I change this behavior so when I sign-out from the other activity and go back to the `LoginActivity`, to have the correct button?

LoginActivity code:

```
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
authStateListener = auth -> {
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
    if (firebaseUser != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
};
```

MainActivity code:

```
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
authStateListener = firebaseAuth -> {
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (firebaseUser == null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are logging out of Firebase and Facebook is still logged in?

Comment: @JamesPoag That was it, I forgot to log-out Facebook, I logged out only Firebase. Thank you James!